# Terminology for dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, notation, finite-groups, terminology, dihedral-groups

What notation is most common for the dihedral group of order $2n$? I'm talking about the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. I know that some books call this group $D_n$, and some books call it $D_{2n}$. There are probably other notations as well.

What notation, if any, is considered more standard? Is there a difference (as there often is) between the US and Europe?

I know that, if I'm writing anything about such a group, I will need to define my notation in context; I'm not asking so that I can be lazy and just use one notation without specifying what it means. I mention this only to prevent people lecturing me about defining my terms in mathematical writing - you would be preaching to the choir. I just wonder what, if anything, people view as "standard".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have to count votes. I've always called it $D_n$.

Comment: This question was asked and discussed in Meta.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27420/465208

Comment: That’s an interesting meta question. No answer, nor really much attempt at evidence...

Comment: @StephenMeskin Would you mind making explicit what you feel the answer is, that is implied by the non-answer? I feel like this is turning into some kind of game. Can we just pull back the curtain, please?

Comment: It seems to happen here often. One person's non-answer is anothers evidence. :-)

Comment: My evidence is the 30 posts I reviewed, one very strong comment in favor, and Wikipedia seeming to move that way. Otherwise the response was split and there wasn't much response, which may indicate a lack of interest. I would very much like to see the results of a review of a significant number of commonly used texts and also of published papers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was evident that in my opinion $D_n$ should denote the Dihedral group of order $2n$

Comment: I've always called it $D_n$, rather than $D_{2n}$ because we call the full symmetric group $S_n$, not $S_{n!}$.

Comment: @StephenMeskin, there is a difference between asking to be treated with respect and disparaging you. I asked you very politely if you could please be less obscure, and you responded by being more obscure. I didn't call you names, I told you how I felt. I felt that way because I had no way of knowing that your comment, following mine, was written without seeing it. I have deleted the comments you didn't like, but they were *not* disparaging. Calling out behavior is not disparaging a person.

Comment: Yes, it was very clear from the start what *you* think the better notation is. I was trying to unpack your obscure comment about "one person's non-answer is another person's evidence." I was never simply asking what you thought the better notation was, because you had made that clear somewhere else, already, albeit somewhat obscurely.

Comment: I found one document online where someone says, without offering supporting evidence, that "Contemporary group theorists prefer $D_{2n}$ over $D_n$." I'm not sure why the writer says that. http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/38175.pdf

Comment: The reason given in that document is not very convincing. Doubling the index does not prevent it from being mistaken for the Dynkin type. And in a context where that is likely, the dihedral group would probably be denoted by its own type, namely $I_2(n)$. I prefer to not double the index, personally.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn’t have made that comment since it wasn’t directly on topic. However, it did respond, if somewhat obscurely, to your comment on getting an answer. The source of my comment was recently reading the 3rd thru 5th comments of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27500/465208 but I have also been told a few times that, with few exceptions, users generally don’t get conclusive answers from these discussions.

Comment: It's whatever, man. I think it's clear that there is *not* a de facto "industry standard", but that plenty of people have preferences that they are willing to state indirectly, discouraging other versions, by claiming that their preferred version is the industry standard, saying "I think most people use...." whichever one they like more. These same people don't actually know what's more common in practice, and have little interest in finding out. That's what I've learned here. While this thread has been going on, I've take an informal survey elsewhere online, with no clear dominant usage.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the notation $D_{2n}$ is mostly used by group theorists while the notation $D_n$ is mostly used by everyone else.

What is the reason group theorists think it's "consistent" to write dihedral groups as $D_{2n}$ but they write symmetric groups as $S_n$ like everyone else instead of $S_{n!}$? I once asked Richard Foote about this ("Would you call the permutations of $5$ letters $S_{120}$?") and here was his answer: in practice, if an abstract symmetric group arises you can nearly always find a set of $n$ things that it permutes, but abstract dihedral groups usually arise with no regular $n$-gon involved in some way, so group theorists prefer to label dihedral groups by their size, just as we *all* do for the quaternion group $Q_8$ (and $Q_{2^n}$, or even more generally $Q_{4m}$). I thought that was a nice explanation, which I use to this day when telling students in a course why I'll write $D_n$ in lectures and course assignments or tests even if the book for the course uses $D_{2n}$.

Comment: Eek, surely the better part of valour is using the textbook's notation unless it's egregiously wrong or misleading (as opposed to not one's preferred convention)? But I am confused--you adduce an argument in favour of $D_{2n}$ as your reason for writing $D_n$?

Comment: I also dare to suggest, with no disrespect meant to Foote, that someone who is an expert in a field, and has spent their professional life using a convention, is most likely to start from that convention and find a reasonable explanation for it (which they will find, due to their expertise).  Which is OK, because, as far as notational conventions go, there is surely no right answer … except for @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez's (currently) [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4565313).

Comment: (As for myself, I will continue to stand, futilely since no-one cares for my opinion on it, on the hill that we must not call a space of moduli a moduli space unless we also call a space of vectors a vectors space.)

Comment: @LSpice  I wasn't offering an argument in favor of $D_{2n}$ to justify using $D_n$, but merely reporting what I was told as an explanation for the usage of $D_{2n}$ and it explained the situation in a way I'd never thought of before. I agree that the explanation probably came after its long usage, but I think it's still worth writing down somewhere.

Comment: I understand your remark about using the book's notation, up to a point.  This semester I am often using $\mathbf Z_m$ and $U(m)$ for $\mathbf Z/(m)$ and $(\mathbf Z/(m))^\times$ in a course since the textbook uses the first notations rather than the second ones, and since the book uses $D_n$ I have no problem there. While $\mathbf Z_p$ to me "really" means the $p$-adic integers, there is nothing $p$-adic in the course. But when I use Dummit & Foote I draw the line at using $D_{2n}$ as in that book because the $D_n$-convention is burned into my brain too much (my "reasonable explanation" :)).

Comment: The number of students who ever complained (in course evalautions or elsewhere) about me using $D_n$ when the textbook uses $D_{2n}$ has been zero.  I do explain the occurrence of both notations in the literature and the Foote story when dihedral groups first come up.

Answer (score 4):

What *should* be common is people being explicit about what they mean when they write $D_n$. Unless your paper is two lines long, writing "where $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$", for example, costs nothing and is worth a lot.

Comment: While I agree with this answer and it's well worth saying, the original post does say "I know that, if I'm writing anything about such a group, I will need to define my notation in context; I'm not asking so that I can be lazy and just use one notation without specifying what it means."